# My javascript variable doesnt update on jquery event handdler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website allows users to post, and also to edit those posts.

When the user wants to edit a post I create a "div" with a "textarea" and a "save" button with jquery and I load whatever the user had in his post in to the "textarea".

```
var textarea = $('<textarea></textarea>');
textarea.attr({
            rows:"2", 
            cols:"56",
            type:"text",
            id:"textedit",
            name:"text"
        });
textarea.text(post_content);
textarea.appendTo(div2);

var save_button = $('<button></button>');
    save_button.attr({
                id:"editChirp",
                value:"Post"
                });

        save_button.text("Save");
        save_button.addClass('button');
        save_button.appendTo(div2);
```

And my jquery event handler for the button is as follows:

```
save_button.click(function () {
            var temp = $('#textedit').val();
            alert(temp);
});
```

The problem is the temp variable doesnt update, it stays to the same value a post was updated the first time.

Comment: You re-declare the variable each time the click event is called.  You need a closure/global scope variable to change.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `textarea.val(post_content);` ?

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions thank you for your reply.
I did try to declare the variable outside the event and only update it inside, but still doesn't work

Comment: @YuriyGalanter No, because post_content is what he originally has, $('#textedit').val() is what he updated the post to be.

Comment: I still don't follow exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So it's an edit box, with the original text, click 'save' with changes.  So you are trying to alert out the updated text?

Comment: Yes @KnowHowSolutions

Comment: Im not selecting any textarea, im creating a textarea with jquery with the post inside of it.
Then I use the value of the created textarea to alert and see the edited post

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/rpzd8/#&togetherjs=frG4IRa5ut

Comment: I agree, just created another fiddle and it works too...http://jsfiddle.net/JveJk/

Comment: You sure there aren't more than one instances of this on the page? id's must be unique. adding two instances of it recreates your issue, aside from obviously there being two textareas.

Comment: The issue is that, there are different posts with different values, so user clicks on edit button, the textarea will have the value of that post loaded to the textare.

The first time the user clicks the save button the value is changed to whatever he edited but when he chooses to edit anothor post and he clicks the save button the value that is alerted is still the same as previous one

Comment: It's the double ID issue then.  Stop using ID's and use classes and use the power of jQuery to find the correct sibling/child textarea.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions I tried adding a class to the textarea I created and get the value using the class name, but still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    save_button.click(function () {
                var temp = $(this).siblings('textarea.myPostText').eq(0);
// eq(0) returns the first sibling found.
                alert(temp.val());
    });
```

Sample with siblings.  Given a fixed structure, you can just query for the sibling of the button, it should always return just the one textarea.  Then the restriction is you might need to change your structure to provide the *uniqueness* required.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GUsDg/3/

Comment: It alerts me [object Object]